# C++ program freezes with 100% CPU in the middle of cout statement

Tags: c++, mysql, deadlock, cout

I'm writing a simple graph generator that stores the graphs in a MySQL database.

Here's the output:

> Connecting to database...Success!
>
> Checking for unfinished vertices...Completed last n = 7
>
> Creating n8 table...Success!

Notice it doesn't print "Generating..." which is part of the same statement. It freezes just like this with 100% CPU. The table does actually get created in the database.

Also, If I start from n = 1, it runs until n7 and then freezes.

Here's the code (not the entire thing, just this part):

```
int main()
{
  int n = 0;
  if (initialize(n)) {
    int limit = 8;
    if (limit >= n) {
      for (; n <= limit; n++) {
        stringstream qs;
        qs << "CREATE TABLE n" << n << " (idbin TEXT("
           << getLengthOfBinaryByN(n) << ") NOT NULL,vertices INT NOT NULL)";
        cout << "Creating n" << n << " table...";
        if (runQuery(qs.str())) {
          cout << "Success!" << endl
               << "Generating all graphs on " << n << " vertices";

          generateGraphs(n);
        } else {
          cout << "Failed!" << endl;
        }
      }
    } else {
      cout << "ERROR: Must be greater than or equal to " << n << endl;
      return 1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

After some research I found that a "deadlock" may be occurring, but I have no idea how to fix that. Any ideas?

Here's the runQuery function if that helps:

```
/*
  runQuery: runs the sql query, assumes that database connected successfully
  Parameters: query
  returns a bool
*/
bool runQuery(string query)
{
  try {
    stmt = con->createStatement();
    res = stmt->executeQuery(query);
    delete stmt;
  } catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
    if (e.getErrorCode() != 0 && e.getErrorCode() != 1050) {
      cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__
           << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " << __LINE__ << endl
           << "# ERR: " << e.what()
           << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode()
           << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: add a `'\n'` at the end of `"vertices"` and try again.

Comment: Output is buffered until you print a newline. So it's probably stuck in `generateGraphs`. Using a debugger would have told you that.

Comment: I suppose that the problem is in `generateGraphs()`; could you show it?

Comment: `<< "Generating all graphs on " << n << " vertices";` doesn't flush the stream so it is locking up in generateGraphs(n);  To see that use this: `<< "Generating all graphs on " << n << " vertices" << endl;`   You could always single step the generateGraphs() function with your debugger to see what is happening.

Comment: @max66  adding a \n won't make the text display will it?  You need to flush the stream with endl don't you?

Comment: @Jerry Jeremiah: you're right: only `std::endl` ensure the flush of the stream; I always mix-up with `\n` and `std::endl`

Comment: @Barmar Yup. You were right.  Turns out I accidentally removed the exit case in the recursive method in generateGraphs.

Comment: For future reference, a deadlock would have got your code stuck with 0% CPU.

Comment: @triggdev That should have eventually produced a stack overflow, unless it's tail-recursive and you compiled with optimization.